# Как в WPF программно создать контрол

Tags: c#, wpf

Как "заспавнить" нужный мне контролл, а именно Image, в определенной точке определенного родителя через код? В WF это делается добавлением контролла в массив элементов родителю, а как делать тоже самое в WPF я не нашел

Comment: Вам не должно этого хотеться. В WPF вы не конструируете UI императивным способом, а описываете то, что вы хотите получить, декларативно, в XAML.

Comment: @VladD Ну, мне надо сделать много однотипных элементов. Вы предлагаете это делать пресетами в XAML? Или как?

Comment: Через `ItemsControl` проще всего, например.

Comment: Вот пример с созданием ста шестиугольников: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/632894/10105

Comment: @VladD В моём случае кол-во и тип объектов будет зависеть от условия. Будет странно, если я буду к каждому условию делать пресет. Я думаю будет лучше сгенирировать

Comment: А вы почитайте пример повнимательнее. Там количество элементов тоже задаётся отдельно и нигде жёстко не прописано.

Comment: @VladD Окей, посмотрю, спасибо. Похоже я плохо понимаю всю систему в WPF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

во всех контролах `WPF` с множеством дочерних элементов есть свойство `Children`

пример использования:

```
var img = new Image(...);
HouseCanvas.Children.Add(img);
Canvas.SetLeft(img, 20); //позиционирование 
Canvas.SetTop(img, 20); //позиционирование
```

Comment: Ну не так чтобы во всех. У `Border`, например, нету.

Comment: Пожалуйста! [15 символов]