# Боковые меню в приложениях WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Какие способы сделать такое боковое меню в WPF?
[image: Менюшка]

Что это? Похоже на ListBox сгрупированное? Menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В принципе, ничего сложного нет, просто стилизуйте стоковое меню.

У меня получилось вот как.

VM-класс для одного пункта:

```
class MenuItemVM : VM
{
    public ObservableCollection<MenuItemVM> ChildItems { get; } =
        new ObservableCollection<MenuItemVM>();

    Geometry icon;
    public Geometry Icon
    {
        get => icon;
        set => Set(ref icon, value);
    }

    string text;
    public string Text
    {
        get => text;
        set => Set(ref text, value);
    }

    string groupName;
    public string GroupName
    {
        get => groupName;
        set => Set(ref groupName, value);
    }

    int? itemCount;
    public int? ItemCount
    {
        get => itemCount;
        set => Set(ref itemCount, value);
    }

    Color itemColor;
    public Color ItemColor
    {
        get => itemColor;
        set => Set(ref itemColor, value);
    }
}
```

Класс `VM` можно стащить, например, [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/632894/10105):

```
class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
            return false;

        field = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Структура меню:

```
IEnumerable<MenuItemVM> BuildMenu()
{
    return new[]
    {
        new MenuItemVM()
        {
            Icon = Geometry.Parse("M0,0 L1,0 L1,1 L0,1 L0,0 L1,1 M1,0 L0,1"),
            Text = "Dashboards",
            GroupName = "Apps",
            ChildItems =
            {
                new MenuItemVM() { Text = "Dashboard1" },
                new MenuItemVM() { Text = "Dashboard2" }
            }
        },
        new MenuItemVM()
        {
            Icon = Geometry.Parse("M0,0 L1,0 L1,1 L0,1 L0,0 L1,1 M1,0 L0,1"),
            Text = "Calendar",
            GroupName = "Apps"
        },
        new MenuItemVM()
        {
            Icon = Geometry.Parse("M0,0 L1,0 L1,1 L0,1 L0,0 L1,1 M1,0 L0,1"),
            Text = "Mail",
            GroupName = "Apps",
            ItemCount = 25,
            ItemColor = Colors.Red
        },
        new MenuItemVM()
        {
            Icon = Geometry.Parse("M0,0 L1,0 L1,1 L0,1 L0,0 L1,1 M1,0 L0,1"),
            Text = "Coming Soon",
            GroupName = "Pages"
        }
    };
}
```

```
DataContext = BuildMenu();
```

Теперь XAML:

```
<Menu VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <Menu.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type media:Geometry}">
            <Path Width="12" Height="12" Margin="2" Data="{Binding}"
                  Stretch="Uniform" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <!--Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Text}"/-->
            <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{Binding Icon}"/>
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding ChildItems}"/>
            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                            <Border CornerRadius="7" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Padding="5,2">
                                <Border.Background>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding ItemColor}"/>
                                </Border.Background>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="GroupedMenu" Source="{Binding}">
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="GroupName"/>
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </Menu.Resources>
    <MenuItem ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupedMenu}}"
              Icon="{x:Null}" Style="{x:Null}">
        <MenuItem.Header>
            <Geometry>M0,0 L2,0 M0,1 L2,1 M0,2 L2,2</Geometry>
        </MenuItem.Header>
        <MenuItem.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="4" /> 
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </MenuItem.GroupStyle>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле это может быть чем угодно, можно только гадать. Один из простых способов сделать это - использовать `ItemsControl` (функциональность выделения элементов списка, как в `ListBox`, тут не нужна, точнее, я так понимаю, что некоторые элементы выделяются, а некоторые показывают выпадающий список, так что зависит от того, как работают пункты меню, из картинки непонятно) с группировкой элементов и потрудиться над переопределением стилей группы и элемента в зависимости от содержимого.

Если исходное приложение написано на WPF, можете использовать **[Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/)**, чтобы посмотреть разметку.