# TwoWay Binding для Dictionary<Enum, bool?>

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Есть несколько checkbox'ов с тремя состояниями: включено, исключено, не установлено.

Эти checkbox'ы представляют из себя фильтры. В ViewModel они реализованы в виде словаря, где ключ это определённый фильтр (checkbox), а значение это его состояние.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ключ у меня это тип перечисления. 
Каждая категория фильтров это отдельный словарь со своим перечислимым типом в ключе.

Например, вот Статус:

```
public enum TitleStatus { anons, ongoing, latest, released }
...
Dictionary<TitleStatus, bool?> TitleStatusFilter { get; set; }
```

Как словарь привязать словарь к checkbox'ам?
Когда я пытаюсь сделать что-то вроде

```
<!-- xmlns:lib="clr-namespace:ShikiApiLib;assembly=ShikiApiLib" -->
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=TitleStatus[ShikiApiLib.TitleStatus.released]}" IsThreeState="True">Вышедшее</CheckBox>
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=TitleStatus[lib:TitleStatus.released]}" IsThreeState="True">Вышедшее</CheckBox>
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding TitleStatus[ShikiApiLib.TitleStatus.released]}" IsThreeState="True">Вышедшее</CheckBox>
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding TitleStatus[lib:TitleStatus.released]}" IsThreeState="True">Вышедшее</CheckBox>
```

Ни один из способов не работает, ибо TitleStatus всё время null, независимо от положения checkbox'ов =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Непосредственно на ваш вопрос: будет работать такой простой XAML:

```
<CheckBox IsThreeState="True" IsChecked="{Binding TitleStatus[released]}">Released</CheckBox>
<CheckBox IsThreeState="True" IsChecked="{Binding TitleStatus[ongoing]}">Ongoing</CheckBox>
<CheckBox IsThreeState="True" IsChecked="{Binding TitleStatus[anons]}">Announced</CheckBox>
```

внутри `StackPanel` показывает следующее:

[image: картинки! картинки!]

Дело в том, что для enum-значений есть конвертер, который конвертирует из строк в enum. И он в некоторых случаях (когда framework знает ожидаемый тип) применяется.

---

Но это скорее всего не будет работать как вам нужно: словари не имплементируют `INotifyPropertyChanged`, а значит, изменённые значения не будут подхватываться. То есть если в другой части программы будет изменено значение в словаре, ваш UI этого «не заметит».

На VM-уровне заведите просто `ObservableCollection` классов, которые имплементируют `INotifyPropertyChanged` и содержат и ключ, и значение как свойства.

Получится что-то такое:

```
class FilterItemVM : VM
{
    public FilterItemVM(TitleStatus status) { Status = status; }

    public TitleStatus Status { get; }

    bool? v;
    public bool? Value
    {
        get { return v; }
        set { Set(ref v, value); }
    }
}
```

(базовый класс VM можно взять, например, [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/632894/10105))

Ваш XAML будет, например, таким:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TitleStatus}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox
                IsThreeState="True"
                Content="{Binding Status}"
                IsChecked="{Binding Value}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Результат:

[image: ещё картинки!]

Обратите внимание, что здесь у вас здесь имена берутся из названий enum-элементов, так что для «красивых» имён может понадобиться дополнительный конвертер.

---

**Обновление**: Поскольку список у вас в реальности неизменный, то `ObservableCollection` по идее не нужна. Для этого случая подойдёт комбинированный вариант с `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
class FilterItemValueVM : VM
{
    bool? v;
    public bool? Value
    {
        get { return v; }
        set { Set(ref v, value); }
    }
}
```

```
TitleStatus = new Dictionary<TitleStatus, FilterItemValueVM>
{
    [TitleStatus.released] = new FilterItemValueVM() { Value = false },
    [TitleStatus.ongoing] = new FilterItemValueVM() { Value = null },
    [TitleStatus.anons] = new FilterItemValueVM() { Value = true }
}
```

```
<StackPanel>
    <CheckBox IsThreeState="True" IsChecked="{Binding TitleStatus[released].Value}">
        Released
    </CheckBox>
    <CheckBox IsThreeState="True" IsChecked="{Binding TitleStatus[ongoing].Value}">
        Ongoing
    </CheckBox>
    <CheckBox IsThreeState="True" IsChecked="{Binding TitleStatus[anons].Value}">
        Announced
    </CheckBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Результат выглядит так же, как и на первой картинке.

Comment: но как тогда реализовать обращение по ключу? если в code-behind можно выкрутится с помощью LINQ, то как делать привязку по ключу в XAML?

Comment: @Mr.Modest: Это не нужно, во второй части ответа написано, как делать.

Comment: я же правильно понял, что вы предлагаете создать ObservableCollection типа KeyValue?

Comment: @Mr.Modest, да, только не `KeyValue`, а какой-то `MyClass`, который содержит нужные вам свойства - `TitleStatus Status` и `bool? IsOn`, например

Comment: @Андрей допустим у меня есть такой класс. Как мне привязать нужный элемент коллекции (с нужным ключом) к соответствующему checkbox'у?

Comment: @Андрей: Дополнительное свойство в VM концептуально нехорошо, т. к. отображаемое имя — это забота View, а не VM.

Comment: В последнем xaml не будет конфликта с встроенным свойством словаря "Value"?

Comment: @Mr.Modest: У меня вроде не наблюдается, я код проверял у себя.

Comment: @VladD спасибо, попробую, когда буду за компом.. первый вариант тоже пригодится, чтобы фильтр жанров добавить (там больше 100 checkbox'ов получится :) )

Comment: @Mr.Modest: Раз их сто, может быть, имеет смысл второй вариант с `ItemsControl`