# Помогите реализовать обновление данных в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, json.net

Господа, помогите реализовать грамотное обновление данных.

Работа приложения:

- Событие скачивает периодически JSON файл.
- Подписанным методом на событие читаем с помощью `Load();` этот файл и заносим все данные в некую модель.
- Делаем привязку данных и выводим.

На данный момент имею такой "костыль" (удаляем старую привязку к данным и привязываем по новой):

```
 if (alertbox.ItemsSource != null) alertbox.ItemsSource = null;
 alertbox.ItemsSource = News.Data.Posts;
```

Нужно от этого собственно избавится.
Пытался реализовать `INotifyPropertyChanged`, но данные, что бы я не делал, остаются старые...

---

**Собственно сам код:**

Загрузка данных из JSON файла (основной метод `Read` и для удобства статичный `Load`):

```
internal class Game
{
    private static GameView Read(string fileName)
    {
        GameView data;
        using (var file = File.OpenText(fileName))
        {
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            data = (GameView) serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(GameView));
        }

        return data;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Основные игровые данные.
    /// </summary>
    public static GameView Data;

    /// <summary>
    ///     Загружаем JSON файл с игровыми данными.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filename">Путь до JSON файла</param>
    public static void Load(string filename = "temp")
    {
        if (filename == "temp") filename = $"{Settings.Program.Directories.Temp}/GameData.json";
        Data = Read(filename);
    }
}
```

Модель `GameView`:

```
public class GameView
{
    public int Version { get; set; }
    public string MobileVersion { get; set; }
    public string BuildLabel { get; set; }
    public int Time { get; set; }
    public int Date { get; set; }
    public List<Alert> Alerts { get; set; }
    public List<double> ProjectPct { get; set; }
    public string WorldSeed { get; set; }
}

public class Alert
{
    [JsonProperty("_id")]
    public Id Id { get; set; }
    public Activation Activation { get; set; }
    public Expiry Expiry { get; set; }
    public MissionInfo MissionInfo { get; set; }
}

public class MissionInfo
{
    public string MissionType { get; set; }
    public string Faction { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string LevelOverride { get; set; }
    public string EnemySpec { get; set; }
    public int MinEnemyLevel { get; set; }
    public int MaxEnemyLevel { get; set; }
    public double Difficulty { get; set; }
    public int Seed { get; set; }
    public int MaxWaveNum { get; set; }
    public MissionReward MissionReward { get; set; }
    public string ExtraEnemySpec { get; set; }
    public List<string> CustomAdvancedSpawners { get; set; }
    public bool? ArchwingRequired { get; set; }
    public bool? IsSharkwingMission { get; set; }
}
```

Как вызываю:

```
Game.Load();
alertbox.ItemsSource = Game.Data.Alerts;
```

Ну и самый простой на данный момент `ListBox`:

```
<ListBox x:Name="alertbox" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate >
                            <Label Content="{Binding MissionInfo.Location}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

Помогите в этом случае реализовать поддержку обновления данных в интерфейсе, как только загрузится JSON файл.
Весь проект залит на [GitHub](https://github.com/arrer/WarframeAgent/tree/master/Agent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала, у вас не получится привязка к полям. Привязка должна быть к свойствам.

Затем, привязка к статическим свойствам неудобна, да и игра — сущность самостоятельная, так что вам имеет смысл сделать методы и свойства класса `Game` нестатическими. Кроме того, вы должны бы реализовать `INotifyPropertyChanged`, не вижу этого в вашем коде.

Берём базовый класс `VM` [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/632894/10105), пишем:

```
internal class Game : VM
{
    private static GameView Read(string fileName)
    {
        GameView data;
        using (var file = File.OpenText(fileName))
        {
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            data = (GameView) serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(GameView));
        }

        return data;
    }

    GameView data;
    public GameView Data { get => data; set => Set(ref data, value); }

    public void Load(string filename = "temp")
    {
        if (filename == "temp")
            filename = $"{Settings.Program.Directories.Temp}/GameData.json";
        Data = Read(filename);
    }
}
```

Далее, внутренние классы у вас иммутабельные? Если нет, им тоже нужно реализовать `INotifyPropertyChanged`. А списку нужно реализовывать `INotifyCollectionChanged`, то есть по идее вам нужна просто `ObservableCollection<T>`:

```
public class GameView : VM
{
    int version;
    public int Version
    {
        get => version;
        set => Set(ref version, value);
    }

    // ...

    ObservableCollection<Alert> alerts;
    public ObservableCollection<Alert> Alerts
    {
        get => alerts;
        set => Set(ref alerts, value);
    }

    // ...
}
```

и то же самое для остальных классов, к которым вы планируете привязку.

Имея это, можно организовывать привязку в XAML.

```
<ListBox Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" ItemsSource="{Binding Data.Alerts}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <Label Content="{Binding MissionInfo.Location}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59790/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd------wpf).