# Помогите с реализацией Event события при добавление уникального элемента в ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, json.net

Господа, подскажите как можно создать некое событие (`Event`), на которое можно подписаться в `ViewModel` с реализованным `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Недавно я задавал вопрос, где мне помогли реализовать обновление интерфейса путем `INotifyPropertyChanged`, там работа проекта была следующая:

- Эвентом, раз в N секунд загружался с сервера JSON файл локально.
- Дальше, подписанным событием выполнялось действие `Load();` , которое загружало весь этот JSON в `ViewModel`.
- Ну и посредством простого `Binding` выводилось значение в `ListBox`.

Сам вопрос (с необходимым кодом, да и ссылкой на GitHub) можно посмотреть по [этой ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/663112/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-wpf).

Собственно сейчас нужно попытаться реализовать проверку на добавление **уникального** элемента в коллекцию `Alerts` и задействовать на событие (с помощью которого в последующем будет выводится уведомление о новом игровом событие). Также путем этого события надо получить данные этого уникального элемента в коллекции (для подробного вывода информации при уведомление, а также записи истории этих событий в файл).

---

Также возник вопрос по привязке: Как привязать `string` значение к обычному `Lable` с привязанной к `DataContent` окна `ViewModel`?

Comment: Привязка к свойству из VM `<Label Content="{Binding Property}" />`

Comment: @Bulson А если к примеру надо привязаться к другой ViewModel, но основное окно должно привязано быть к изначальной ViewModel (скажем вывести данные сразу из всех разделов на 1 странице). В таком случае тогда где мне задавать DataContent?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ: А где вы хотите создать событие? В VM? В чём проблема, есть же [стандартный `event`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9aackb16(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @VladD К сожалению я не как не могу понять, как отслеживать именно уникальные элементы добавленные в коллекцию. Теоретически мне надо в коде ViewModel, в коллекции Alerts реализовать проверку по уникальному параметру Oid и в ней смотреть, был ли этот ID ранее, или нет. Если нет - должен срабатывать эвент. Также не смог разобраться как с помощью эвента передавать данные элемента, который вызвал это событие.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ: Окей, ну эта часть как раз лёгкая, вы можете, например, просто завести множество (или мультимножество) всех ID. А для кого вы собираетесь передавать ивент?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ: Расскажите лучше, какая ваша задача и для чего вам это нужно. У меня есть подозрение, что вы решаете задачу неправильно.

Comment: @VladD Я сейчас переписываю свой старый проект под новый лад. Проект собирает игровые данные в виде JSON с сервера и отображает их в виде удобного для пользователя интерфейса. В этом JSON файле есть несколько категорий (`Alerts` одна из них), в них время от времени появляются новые события. Вот эти события мне нужно отследить и вывести уведомление (скажем: "Через 10 минут начнется событие в локации *, требуемый уровень 10-20"). На данный момент я имею список всех событий, но не могу отследить появление новых (тех, которых нету сейчас уже в списке).

Comment: @VladD Раньше, проект был написан без всякого рода привязок, моделей, эвентов и тому подобное и в нем я это реализовывал двумя List-ами, в одном хранил текущие Id (благо сервер генерирует их уникальные), а в другом держал id сервера, дальше делал проверку и то, что отличается по сути и было новое. Тогда я и выводил нужное уведомление и легко получал нужные данные (благо был обычный List). Сейчас же я взял для себя новое, привязки ViewModel и так далее и не до конца еще освоил их, вот по этому я не знаю, как реализовать грамотно проверку на добавление нового элемента и вывести уведомление.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ: Ага, я понял. Смотрите. Общение с сервером — это вовсе не дело VM, это дело модели. Она пусть содержит `HashSet<id>`, в новом JSON получает список id, и каждый из них, который не присутствует в списке, является новым.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ: Обнаружив новый элемент/новые элементы, модель отправляет event. VM подписывается на event и добавляет новый VM-элемент в `ObservableCollection<ЧегоТоТамVM>`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ: Посмотрите вот тут немного теории: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/379331/10105

Comment: @VladD Я был бы очень вам признателен, если напишете небольшой пример с использованием всего этого.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ: Ну попробую :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну что ж, давайте попробуем написать пример. Проблема в том, что вам нужно разделить модельную функциональность (а именно модель должна заниматься чтением интернета, разбором JSON и тому подобными занятиями) и функциональность VM (которая управляет всем и готовит данные для отображения).

Итак, начнём с модели. Мы следим за списком нотификаций, давайте заведём класс `NotificationWatcher` и поместим его в namespace `Model`.

```
class NotificationWatcher
{
```

Какая нам нужна функциональность? Ну, нам нужно начать слежение и окончить его. Сделаем это в фоновом потоке, и используем TPL. Оформим само слежение в виде метода `Watch`, мы должны его запустить и остановить по требованию. Для остановки будем применять `CancellationToken`, как и положено.

```
    CancellationTokenSource cts;
    public void Start()
    {
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Task.Run(() => Run(cts.Token));
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        cts.Cancel();
        cts = null;
    }
```

В методе `Start` мы просто запускаем `Watch` в фоновом потоке с токеном. А в методе `Stop` включаем отмену задания по этому токену. Всё просто! Дальше, сам метод `Watch` будет просто каждую секунду осуществлять при помощи метода `EvaluateList`, и наблюдать за токеном:

```
    async void Watch(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        var pause = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        try
        {
            while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await Task.Delay(pause, ct);
                await EvaluateList(ct);
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException) when (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        { }
    }
```

Пока просто?

Теперь, метод `EvaluateList`. Он должен загрузить JSON-список, распарсить его в объектное представление, и найти, какие же из нотификаций новые. Для этого нам понадобится класс, соответствующий одной нотификации. Отвлечёмся от класса `NotificationWatcher` на время, и напишем его. Он у нас будет совсем простым (а у вас наверное сложнее, т. к. он должен будет отражать реальный JSON с сервера):

```
class Notification
{
    public int ID;
    public string Text;
}
```

Проще не бывает. Вернёмся к классу `NotificationWatcher`. Итак:

```
    HashSet<int> currentIds = new HashSet<int>(); // текущие ID

    async Task EvaluateList(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        // получаем JSON
        string json = await DownloadNotifications(ct);
        // превращаем его в список объектов
        var currentNotifications = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Notification>>(json);
        // отбираем из него новые
        var newNotifications =
                currentNotifications.Where(ntf => !currentIds.Contains(ntf.ID));
        // для каждого из новых объектов оповещаем о нём мир
        foreach (var ntf in newNotifications)
        {
            currentIds.Add(ntf.ID); // и запоминаем его ID на будущее, чтобы
                                    // в следующий раз он не считался новым
            FireNewNotification(ntf);
        }
    }
```

Теперь, нотификация. Нотификацию напишем совершенно обыкновенную, через `event`. Как примерные программисты, реализуем паттерн с `EventArgs`. Определяем свой класс, производный от `EventArgs`:

```
class NewNotificationEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public readonly Notification Notification;
    public NewNotificationEventArgs(Notification ntf) { Notification = ntf; }
}
```

Возвращаемся к классу `NotificationWatcher`, и реализуем отправление нотификации:

```
    public event EventHandler<NewNotificationEventArgs> NotificationArrived;
    void FireNewNotification(Notification ntf) =>
        NotificationArrived?.Invoke(this, new NewNotificationEventArgs(ntf));
```

Что осталось? Нам нужно реализовать метод `DownloadNotifications`. У вас он будет читать данные с сервера, но я просто закодирую фейковые данные прямо в коде для простоты примера.

```
    // фейк, тут нужно читать с сервера
    int notificationNo = 0;
    string[] strings =
        {
            "[ { \"ID\": 1, \"Text\": \"Привет\" } ]",
            "[ { \"ID\": 1, \"Text\": \"Привет\" }, { \"ID\": 2, \"Text\": \"Привет\" } ]",
            "[ { \"ID\": 1, \"Text\": \"Привет\" }, { \"ID\": 2, \"Text\": \"Привет\" }, " +
              "{ \"ID\": 3, \"Text\": \"Пока\" } ]",
            "[ { \"ID\": 4, \"Text\": \"Пока\" } ]"
        };
    async Task<string> DownloadNotifications(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        var index = notificationNo >= strings.Length ? strings.Length - 1 : notificationNo;
        await Task.Delay(200);
        notificationNo++;
        return strings[index];
    }
```

И всё!

```
}
```

На этом с моделью мы закончили.

Переходим к VM. Реализация `INotifyPropertyChanged` нам в этом простом примере не понадобится, потому что у нас нету изменяемых полей. Если они у вас появятся, вам понадобится базовый класс `VM`, как [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/632894/10105). VM-классы положим в namespace `ViewModel`.

Для начала, простая вещь — одна нотификация. Она умеет конструироваться из модельной нотификации, но ей не нужен ID, так что она его не запоминает. Кроме того, она будет выставлять свойство, а не поле, как и всякий уважающий себя VM-объект (поскольку к нему будет проводиться привязка):

```
class NotificationVM
{
    public string Text { get; }
    public NotificationVM(Model.Notification ntf) { Text = ntf.Text; }
}
```

Затем, список нотификаций. Положим в него немного логики. Во-первых, он должен выставлять `ObservableCollection` нотификаций. Затем, он должен запускать (и останавливать, но мне лень) модельный `NotificationWatcher`, и подписываться на его события.

```
class NotificationListVM
{
    public ObservableCollection<NotificationVM> Notifications { get; } =
        new ObservableCollection<NotificationVM>();

    Model.NotificationWatcher watcher = new Model.NotificationWatcher();

    public NotificationListVM()
    {
        watcher.NotificationArrived += OnNotificationArrtived;
        watcher.Start();
    }
```

Теперь, что мы делаем, когда приходит нотификация? Для начала, она приходит в каком-то фоновом потоке, но нам нужно работать с публичными свойствами только в UI-потоке. Перебросим выполнение в него. А уж там создадим `NotificationVM` и добавим в список:

```
    void OnNotificationArrtived(object sender, Model.NewNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        // это происходит в модельном потоке
        Application.Current?.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
            // это в UI-потоке
            var ntfVM = new NotificationVM(e.Notification);
            Notifications.Add(ntfVM);
        });
    }
```

Вот и всё с VM.

```
}
```

Теперь, уровень отображения. У нас будет одно простое окно, отображающее список нотификаций в `ItemsControl`'е:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        x:Class="View.MainWindow"
        Title="Тест" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Notifications}" Margin="10">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Ну и стандартный обвязочный код для MVVM-приложения:

App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="Test.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
</Application>
```

App.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        var vm = new ViewModels.NotificationListVM();
        new View.MainWindow() { DataContext = vm }.Show();
    }
}
```

Вот и всё!

Результат:

[image: пока-пока]

---

Если мы хотим следить и за удалением нотификаций, нам нужно немного модифицировать нашу модель:

```
    Dictionary<int, Notification> currentNotifications = new Dictionary<int, Notification>();

    async Task EvaluateList(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        string json = await DownloadNotifications(ct);
        var obtainedNotifications = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Notification>>(json);
        var newNotifications =
              obtainedNotifications.Where(ntf => !currentNotifications.ContainsKey(ntf.ID));
        foreach (var ntf in newNotifications)
        {
            currentNotifications.Add(ntf.ID, ntf);
            FireNewNotification(ntf);
        }
        var removedNotificationIds =
              currentNotifications.Keys.Except(obtainedNotifications.Select(ntf => ntf.ID));
        foreach (var id in removedNotificationIds)
        {
            FireRemovedNotification(currentNotifications[id]);
            currentNotifications.Remove(id);
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<NewNotificationEventArgs> NotificationArrived;
    void FireNewNotification(Notification ntf) =>
        NotificationArrived?.Invoke(this, new NewNotificationEventArgs(ntf));

    public event EventHandler<RemovedNotificationEventArgs> NotificationDeparted;
    void FireRemovedNotification(Notification ntf) =>
        NotificationDeparted?.Invoke(this, new RemovedNotificationEventArgs(ntf));
```

Также нам более не нужен список `currentIds` (его роль играет словарь `currentNotifications`), и нужно добавить класс

```
class RemovedNotificationEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public readonly Notification Notification;
    public RemovedNotificationEventArgs(Notification ntf) { Notification = ntf; }
}
```

Плюс нужна подходящая обработка в VM-уровне.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59797/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd----event---).