# Отсчет времени в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

Имею класс, в классе есть две переменные `long (UnixTime)`, они привязаны через `Binding` к `ProgressBar`. Также отдельно имеется класс, который переводит текущее время в Unix и раз в 5 сек таймером обновляет его. Время также привязано. Все это сделано для красивого отображения того, сколько осталось до конца события.

Сейчас мне нужно создать статус события (Если событие начинается выводим - начнется через : 00:00. Если событие идет - Закончится через: 00:00, ну и другая мелочь). С расчетами времени и тому подобному разберусь сам, но вот как сделать вывод этого времени и что бы оно обновлялось...

Вот в этом собственно и вопрос, как забиндить таймер и читать в нем элементы из класс модели?

В [данной](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/663112/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-wpf) теме можно полностью посмотреть мою модель и как происходит привязка значений.

Класс `Alerts` содержит всю информацию о событиях и в нем значения:

- `long` значение старта события - `Alerts.Activation.Date.NumberLong`
- `long` значение конца события - `Alerts.Expiry.Date.NumberLong`

Желательно сделать в этом классе переменную `State`, которая и будет выводить время.

Comment: Биндиться нужно по идее не к модели, а к VM.

Comment: Вроде всё просто, не? У вас должны быть 3 свойства: Start, End и Current, и вы привязываете к ним Minimum, Maximum и Value у прогрессбара.

Comment: @VladD Вы немного не так поняли, я с баром вроде все сделал. Он рабочий, Value у  меня привязано к отдельному классу, где я просто запускаю таймер и задаю значение DateTime.Now(); переведенное в Unix время. Мне нужно string переменную, где будет происходить вычисление и раз в 1-5 сек обновлять данные. Я вычисления все сделать могу, а вот что бы оно у меня раз в 1-5 сек обновлял значение, к сожалению мозгов пока не хватает.

Comment: Вот это не совсем понял: «Мне нужно string переменную, где будет происходить вычисление и раз в 1-5 сек обновлять данные.» Вычисление должно ж проходить в методе, а не в переменной? И какие данные нужно обновлять?

Comment: [Вот скриншот блока](http://i.imgur.com/1UuWCsV.png) В нем есть у каждого элемента в ListBox время (сейчас оно у всех 00:00), надо вот туда забиндить обратный отсчет до окончания события. Что бы я грубо говоря сделал Text="{Binding Status}" и все, там было время, которое раз в секунду обновлялось бы (обратный отсчет).

Comment: А! Понял! Только зачем вам строка? Положите в ваше свойство `TimeSpan`, и обновляйте его каждую секунду, записывайте туда `EndTime - DateTime.Now`.

Comment: А как обновлять то?) Через Get Set я думаю что то реализовывать, но таким методом у меня только вывести удалось. Время к прогрес бару я и вовсе [таким методом](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3354822/6808809) реализовал.

Comment: Ну, когда к вам приходит событие от таймера, обновляйте все нужные свойства, например. Кстати, вам нужен тот таймер, который доставляет события в UI-потоке. (Ну или перебрасывать туда.)