# Добавить дополнительные значения к коллекции

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Добрый!

Имею привязанную в `XAML` коде коллекцию `List<double>`. В данной коллекции находятся 3 значения, которые не как не меняют свою последовательность. Данные значения берутся из `JSON` (то есть у меня реализована модель того, как JSON выглядит). Так вот, мне необходимо каким то образом добавить дополнительные параметры к коллекции и привязать их к необходимым объектам.

То есть скажем:

1. 85.32567573
2. 12.54654736
3. 0

Нужно первому элементу задать переменную цвет красный и скажем string имя "Вася", а само значение в переменную `double` Value.
Второй элемент цвет зеленый, имя "Егор", ну и Value.
Третий элемент так и вовсе нужно убрать.

Помогите, как лучше реализовать эти "дополнительные" переменные? Я так понимаю мне нужно создать отдельную коллекцию и туда добавлять необходимые значения, но как это все делается в `MVVM` модели? Или можно как то через `Get; Set;` изменить?

Comment: У вас уже разделена логика `View`/`ViewModel`?

Comment: @AGS17: Вы можете посмотреть все, что у меня реализовано по [этому](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/663112/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-wpf)  вопросу. Там мне помогли реализовать чтение данных и их привязку с использованием INotifyCollectionChanged.

Comment: Хорошо. Добавьте код с вьюшки и его вью модели ([править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/671803/edit))

Comment: @AGS17: В ответе, который я Вам предоставил имеется все необходимое (все это у меня в проекте сейчас находится и по сути мало что изменилось). Коллекция значений `public List<double> ProjectPct { get; set; }`. Как данные заносятся из JSON - тоже там есть (в ответе, первый код), а привязка самая простая `{Binding ProjectPct}` к `ListBox`. Или прям принципиально все это продублировать тут?

Comment: Если вам нужно привязать дополнительные параметры, заведите отдельный класс, в который укладывайте ваши значения, цвет и имя, и собирайте не список `double`'ов, а список вот этих ваших объектов.

Comment: @VladD Хорошо, а как быть с чтением JSON? Ведь если я сменю double на класс, то не будет верно производить дессириализацию. А если я создам отдельный список, то как в него добавлять при добавление значения в эту коллекцию?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ: Смотрите. Ваш JSON — это модельный уровень. При переходе к уровню VM у вас из списка double конструируется список VM-объектов, с которым вы и работаете. А когда вам нужно сохранить это всё снова в JSON, то вы конструируете новый список double'ов, и сохраняете его.

Comment: @VladD: Ну сохранять JSON мне не нужно, только чтение данных с сервера. Я сумел прочитать их и засунуть в `List<double>`, но если я изменю его на `List<class>`, то получу ошибку чтения JSON.Net, ибо на сервере идет банальный список double значений. Вы мне не так давно [помогли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/663802) с реализацией отслеживания добавления элементов в коллекцию, думаю может через это попробовать, но должен же быть способ легче)) Если есть, помогите примером пожалуйста!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ: Смотрите. Вы с сервера читаете `List<double>`, и на уровне модели пускай он таким же списком и остаётся. Но на уровне VM превращайте его в список чего-то другого, что вам реально нужно.