# Команда на DoubleClick по элементу ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding StudentsList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStudent}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="10">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding GetGroupNum}" Margin="10,0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Где `StudentList` - коллекция студентов, `SelectedStudent` - конкретный выбранный студент.

Необходимо по двойному нажатию на `ListView`, вызвать команду `EditStudent`. Команды умею привязывать только к `Button`.
Как поступить в этом случае?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Давайте воспользуемся такой штукой как `InputBindings`:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick"
                      Command="{Binding DataContext.EditStudent,
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                              AncestorType=Window}}"
                      CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
    </StackPanel.InputBindings>
    ...
</StackPanel>
```

Это уже работает, но у всех `ItemsControl` есть нюанс - по умолчанию они не растягивают свои элементы, это можно увидеть, если задать `StackPanel` любой цвет в `Background`, поэтому команда будет вызываться только при клике четко по тексту элемента. Исправить это можно, подкорректировав стиль `ListViewItem`:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding StudentsList}" ...>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
...
```

Ну и нужно еще что-то сделать с отступами, так как то что у вас сейчас `StackPanel Margin="10"` вам скорее всего не понравится, например можно обернуть всё в прозрачный `Border` (`InputBindings` теперь переезжают в него, в `StackPanel` они больше не нужны):

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Border Padding="10">
            <Border.InputBindings>
                <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick"
                              Command="{Binding DataContext.EditStudent,
                                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                      AncestorType=Window}}"
                              CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
            </Border.InputBindings>
            <StackPanel>
                ...
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Вот тогда между элементами будут визуальные отступы, но команда будет отрабатывать по клику в любом месте элемента

Comment: Да, Ваш вариант подходит, именно то, что и хотел. Спасибо.

Comment: `MouseBinding`? Круто, не знал, пользовался System.Interactivity вместо этого.

Comment: @VladD, фишка в том еще, что у StackPanel нет события DoubleClick вообще, поэтому Interactivity не понятно как привязать

Comment: @Андрей: Например, на `MouseLeftButtonUp`, как [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/632894/10105).

Comment: @VladD, а количество кликов и время задержки между ними вручную подсчитывать что ли?

Comment: @VladD, кстати, у MouseBinding еще преимущество в том, что можно клавишу-модификатор прямо в разметке указать, типа `Gesture="Alt+MiddleClick"`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.input.mousebinding.gesture(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Хм, и правда, DoubleClick есть только у контролов https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.control.mousedoubleclick(v=vs.110).aspx. То есть пришлось бы навешивать на весь ListView. Но да, это дополнительный геморрой, и может не прокатить в общем случае. Бесспорно, нативный MouseBinding должен быть удобнее.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void ListView_MouseDoubleClick_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        EditStudent();
    }
```

1. Выделите `listview` в конструкторе;
2. Перейдите во вкладку "свойства";
3. Кликните на кнопку с картинкой молнии в верхнем правом углу, ее название "Обработчики событий 
   выбранного элемента", в разных студиях может называться по разному;
4. Найдите событие с именем `MouseDoubleClick`, в пустое поле кликните 2 раза и студия все сделает за Вас;
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: команда находится во VM, таким образом ее вызвать не получится.

Comment: Ну и это клик по ListView, а не по его элементам

Comment: судя по контексту вопроса команда все же находится во VM

Answer (score 0):

```
<ListView>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding EditStudent}" CommandParameter=""/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Это клик по самому ListView, а ТС надо клик по элементу, не так ли? Можно кликнуть 2 раза в любом месте ListView и это событие сработает, даже если в нем нет ни одного элемента

Comment: Дождемся автора чтобы разрешить эту дилемму

Comment: Клик необходим по элементу. Команда во ViewModel.