# Как получить тект Node TreeView на котором произошел ПКМ?

Tags: c#, wpf

При этом Node не выделен. TreeView заполняется через ObservableCollection.

Comment: Используйте команду и InputBingings. Пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/735522/218063

Comment: Это абсолютно ничего не меняет. Как видно в том примере, InputBingings можно прикрутить и к Border. А вообще InputBindings это свойство UIElement, поэтому оно есть у всех контролов

Comment: Нужный вам gesture называется `RightClick`. Вот здесь полный перечень мышиных жестов: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.input.mouseaction(v=vs.110).aspx Их можно использовать также с клавишами-модификаторами: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.input.mousebinding.gesture(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @АндрейNOP Я создал команду и привязываю ее в своем шаблоне TreeViewItem(TreeView многоколоночный) в Border,
обработчик события этой команды помещаю, пока в кодбех MainWindow. Но сам факт размещения в шаблоне кода привязки к команде, делает запуск программы не возможным - <Приложение находится в режиме приостановки>. Вот строка привязки  <CommandBinding Command="local:MyCommands.PkmNode"   Executed="{StaticResource local:PkmNode_Executed}"/>.

Comment: А если написать `Executed="PkmNode_Executed"`?

Comment: Ошибка  корневой элемент "ResourceDictionary" требует атрибута x:Class для поддержки обработчиков событий в файле XAML

Comment: *Ошибка корневой элемент "ResourceDictionary" требует атрибута x:Class для поддержки обработчиков событий в файле XAML* - ну дык вы поместите CommandBinding в разметку окна. Почитайте это: https://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/binding_and_styles_WPF/level9/9_4.php Но вообще, по правильному, команда должна быть у вас во ViewModel (паттерн MVVM)

Comment: @АндрейNOP. Все сработало)) Спасибо)).

Answer (score 2):

Так как св-во TreeView(MouseRightButtonDown) ничего мне не дало,  я воспользовался советом Андрей NOP и использовал команду InputBingings. Итак:

1. Создал команду pkmNode во ViewModel;

   ```
   private static RoutedUICommand pkmNode;
   public static RoutedUICommand PkmNode
   {
       get { return pkmNode; }
   }

   public ViewModel()
   {
       // Инициализация команды
       pkmNode = new RoutedUICommand("pkmNode", "pkmNode", typeof(ViewModel));
   }
   ```
2. Произвел регистрацию команды PkmNode в конструкторе главного окна

   ```
   ViewModel vm;

   public General()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       CommandBinding cb = new CommandBinding();
       vm = new ViewModel(this);
       cb.Command = ViewModel.PkmNode;
       cb.Executed += PkmNode_Executed;
       Window1.CommandBindings.Add(cb);            
       treeView.ItemsSource = vm.LoadNapDB();
   }
   ```
3. В шаблоне TreeViewItem в Border через InputBindings привязую ПКМ к своей команде и передаю текcт Node TreeView на котором произошел ПКМ

   ```
   <Border.InputBindings>
       <MouseBinding Gesture="RightClick"
                     Command="local:ViewModel.PkmNode"
                     CommandParameter="{Binding MyHeader}"/>
   </Border.InputBindings>
   ```
4. Принимаю переданные параметры в своем обработчике команды

   ```
   private void PkmNode_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
   {  
       var d = e.Parameter;  
   }
   ```

Еще раз спасибо Андрею NOP за своевременно указанный путь и помощь. Всем удачи))