# C# WPF MVVM event binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Использую

> xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"

```
 <i:Interaction.Triggers>
   <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
   <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=MouseDownEvent}"/>
 /i:EventTrigger>
```

Как мне получить кнопку которая нажата?

```
public ICommand MouseDownEvent { get; set; } 
public MainViewModel(MainWindow window)
{
    this.MouseDownEvent = new RelayCommand(o => {
    });
}
```

Comment: зачем получать кнопку, которая нажата, во вьюмодели?

Comment: @tym32167 а где? и как мне узнать?

Comment: для чего вам надо это знать?

Comment: @tym32167 мне нужно сделать window.DragMove и узнать MouseButtonEventArgs чтоб обработать doubleclick

Comment: Для этого надо использовать MouseBinding, а не что у вас. Пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/735522/218063 Хотя, конечно, всякие перетаскивания это задача представления и VM о нем знать не должен

Comment: не уверен, что делать это во вью модели правильно, но если вам надо что то передать в команду, вы можете воспользоваться свойством CommandArgument там же, где биндите команду.

Comment: @tym32167 как я понимаю VM должна связывать View и Model. В моем случае Model window? нет?

Comment: нет. Есть View, есть Model, между ними есть ViewModel. А Window - это просто контрол, который помогает представлению