# Как в элементе ListView WPF получить выделенный Item его номер

Tags: wpf

Как в элементе `ListView WPF` получить выделенный `Item`? Я привязал событие двойного клика и в обработчике мне нужно получить данные о выбранном элементе.
Если на форме я биндюсь к свойству А, то как мне получить доступ к этому свойству ,  при выделенной строке. На формах это возможно, а в WPF не знаю как
Вот код обработчика:

```
private void Control_OnMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) 
{
            MessageBox.Show("hfhfdh");

            ListView lV = (ListView) sender;
            //var cliItem = lV.ItemContainerGenerator. // тут пытаюсь добраться до элемента

             if (lV.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            var ggg = lV.SelectedItem; // вижу в отладчике полностью все, что нужно. достать не могу
        }

}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Команда на DoubleClick по элементу ListView](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/735451/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-doubleclick-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%83-listview)

Comment: @АндрейNOP Нет у меня вопрос про другое, я не могу вытащить свойство,к которому хочу обратиться,  то есть при двойном клике на выделенную строку в ListView я в обработчике событий получаю объект, из которого состоит строка и в объекте все свойства вижу, но добраться до них не могу.

Comment: Используйте приведение: `var ggg =  (MyClass)lV.SelectedItem`

Comment: @АндрейNOP Спасибо помогло