# WPF и MVVM, команда нажатия по элементу ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Я сделал вот такой простой ListView и забиндил данные в него:

```
   <ListView Grid.Column="0" DockPanel.Dock="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding BindData}" SelectionMode="Single">
     <ListView.View>
       <GridView>
         <GridView.Columns>
           <GridViewColumn>
             <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}">
                     <TextBlock.InputBindings>
                         <MouseBinding Command="{Binding DataContext.AddTitlesInTable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBox}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"  MouseAction="LeftClick" />
                     </TextBlock.InputBindings>
                    </TextBlock>
                   </DataTemplate>                                                   
                 </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                  <GridViewColumn.Header>
                   <TextBlock Text="{x:Static res:Resource.DataHeader}"  />
                  </GridViewColumn.Header>
                </GridViewColumn>
               </GridView.Columns>
              </GridView>
         </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Я бы хотел, чтобы команда *AddTitlesInTable* срабатывала по нажатию на всей строке ListView. Но сейчас она работает только если нажать на текст, то есть вложенный элемент TextBlock. Как можно реализовать подобное?

Comment: Отличный вопрос на самом деле! По идее надо не в DataTemplate это делать, а править шаблон самого ListViewItem. DataTemplate — это шаблон содержимого элемента, а не самого элемента.

Comment: @АндрейNOP идея интересная, но я не настолько силён в XAML, чтобы реализовать :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP придумал решение с помощью триггеров, ниже обликовал ответ

Comment: Если будет время, попробую завтра написать ответ

Comment: А пока можете попробовать решение отсюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/735522/218063

Comment: Как оказалось, там все не очень просто, MouseBinding перехватывает мышиный клик и Item не получает фокус. А вообще можете взять стандартный шаблон отсюда https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/listview-styles-and-templates (см. там `<Style x:Key="{x:Type ListViewItem}" TargetType="ListViewItem">`) и поэкспериментировать с ним, добавить InputBindings к `GridViewRowPresenter` и т. п. Ну и еще решение которое вам лучше всего подойдет будет зависеть от того, что конкретно вы хотите сделать. Что делает навешиваемая команда и т. д.

Comment: @АндрейNOP спасибо, пойду читать :)

Answer (score 0):

Собственно я использовал взаимодействие команд и событий, отлавливаю событие *SelectionChanged* и перенаправляю его и выделенный элемент в свою команду:

```
<ListView Name="ListView1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding DeteriorationSystemPartsGroupsModelData}" Margin="10,10,10,10">
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
   <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
      <i:InvokeCommandAction 
          Command="{Binding AddTitlesInTable}"
          CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ListView1, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
      </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
 <ListView.View>
... etc
```

Проверено, команда получает выделенную строку, и нажимать можно в любом месте, команда отрабатывает на 100%

Comment: Ну SelectionChanged это не обязательно LeftClick, текущий элемент и с помощью клавиатуры можно сменить. Поэтому это решение не равнозначно

Comment: @АндрейNOP спасибо, попробую, и подожду тогда пример