# Двойной клик на TreeViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

Есть проводник который сделан с помощью TreeView. И хотелось бы что бы при двойном клике на папке выполнялось определённое действие. Если событие подвязать к TreeViewItem то на двойной клик реагирует и треугольничек который разворачивает/сворачивает узел TreeView. 
А возможно ли сделать что бы событие срабатывало только когда кликаем по названию папки? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

XAML

```cs
     <TreeView Name="catalog" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="5" 
                  TreeViewItem.Expanded="catalogExpanded" TreeViewItem.Selected="getFolder">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image Name="img"  Width="16" Height="16" Stretch="Fill"
                                        Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                        AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}, Path=Header,
                                        Converter={x:Static local:HeaderToImageConverter.Instance}}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="5,0" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>
```

Comment: Покажите разметку

Comment: Добавил разметку

Comment: Ну тут вариант в лоб, это подцепить событие клика на StackPanel. Сделать это можно через Interaction триггер https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25435134/how-can-i-trigger-an-event-when-the-left-mouse-button-gets-released-in-wpf/25435302
Второй вариант, это изменить Template TreeViewItem (не HeaderTemplate),
Третий вариант, создать свой контрол, унаследованный от TreeViewItem, но при это все равно необходимо изменять шаблон контрола

Comment: Вот, похоже то что вам надо: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/735522/218063

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В моём случае оказалось до банальности просто: обернуть панель стека в элемент управления, который поддерживает событие двойного клика.

```cs
<ContentControl MouseDoubleClick="DoubleClick" >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        ...
    </StackPanel>
</ContentControl>
```