# Как обработать двойной клик по отдельному элементу (item) ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Есть окно, содержащее, помимо прочего, элемент `ListView`. Есть задача – при двойном клике на отдельной строке списка (`Item`) производить определённое действие.

Мой вариант решения – обрабатывать событие `PreviewMouseDoubleClick` и потом получать выбранную строку из свойства `SelectedItem` – работает. Однако событие происходит даже в тех случаях, когда двойной клик совершается не по строке списка, а просто по любой части этого `ListView`. Самый глупый пример – я быстро дважды кликаю по стрелке на полосе прокрутки, чтобы увидеть следующие элементы списка, и это распознаётся как двойной клик по `ListView` (очевидно, потому что полоса прокрутки является элементом `ListView`) и, соответственно, производится действие, которое по задумке должно было произойти только при двойном клике на строке списка.

Вопрос: как обрабатывать двойной клик именно по `Item`-у списка, а не по любой его части?

Comment: Варианты разные есть. Если говорить про событие, то можно так: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728205/wpf-listview-attaching-a-double-click-on-an-item-event . Если говорить про команду, то можно так: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/735451/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-doubleclick-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%83-listview

Comment: @alladuh спасибо большое, гуглил только на русском, потому не нашёл это. Попробую.