# Работа на Гексагональной сеткой

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте, я столкнулся с проблемой создание гексагональной сети в WPF и одно интересно решение в вопросе [Гексагональная сетка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/632517/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0?answertab=votes#tab-top) .Я начинающий программист самоучка и решил оживить пример и потом про экспериментировать с ним, но столкнулся с такой проблемами как:

```
xmlns:view="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
// дальше строки
<view:FieldPositionToCoordinateXConverter x:Key="XConv"/>
<view:FieldPositionToCoordinateYConverter x:Key="YConv"/>
```

Последние строчки не работают так как пишет что view не обнаружено.
А так же данная библиотека вообще не обнаружена :

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

и из-за этого возникают проблемы.
А так же в коде на С# не обнаружена вот эта строчка:

```
new RelayCommand(OnActivate);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. У вас должны быть классы `FieldPositionToCoordinateXConverter` и `FieldPositionToCoordinateYConverter` в пространстве имён `WpfApplication1`. Убедитесь, что они там действительно есть.
2. Подключите System.Windows.Interactivity.dll. Для этого можно, например, установить Expression Blend SDK:

   [image: анимашка]
3. `RelayCommand` должен быть в вашем MVVM-фреймворке. Если вы не пользуетесь фреймворками, можно определить самостоятельно. Например, так:

   ```
   class RelayCommand : RelayCommand<object>
   {
       public RelayCommand(Action execute) : base(_ => execute()) { }
       public RelayCommand(Action execute, Func<bool> canExecute) :
           base(_ => execute(), _ => canExecute()) { }
   }

   class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand
   {
       protected readonly Predicate<T> canExecute;
       protected readonly Action<T> execute;

       public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

       public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute) : this(execute, _ => true) { }

       public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute, Predicate<T> canExecute)
       {
           this.execute = execute ??
                   throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));
           this.canExecute = canExecute ??
                   throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(canExecute));
       }

       public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => canExecute((T)parameter);
       public void Execute(object parameter) => execute((T)parameter);

       public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged() =>
           CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
   }
   ```