# Как поменять цвет фона формы из другой формы?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как поменять цвет фона формы из другой формы, не при помощи кнопки, а, например,через RichTextBox то есть пишешь цвет и меняется на заданный?

Comment: А что конкретно не получается? Вам во второй форме просто нужно иметь ссылку на первую и в обработчика клика по кнопке применить пишете `form1.Background = ...;`

Comment: Насколько я понимаю,то что Вы написали просто меняет цвет после каждого нажатия на кнопку,но мне не нужна кнопка . А у меня не получается в одной форме в Richtextbox писать цвет,а в другой форме он должен меняться

Comment: @Veronika, ну тогда делайте тоже самое не в обработчике клика по кнопке, а в обработчике TextChanged (или как он там называется) вашего ричтекстбокса

Comment: Когда я пишу ссылку на первую форму где должен меняться цвет, 
пишет Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства "Form.BackColor" требуется ссылка на объект. Принимает 
DefaultBackColor, но зачем мне он?

Comment: @Veronika, когда открываете второе окно, передавайте ему ссылку на первое, например, параметром.

Answer (score 1):

Например, на WPF делается очень просто.

XAML:

```
<Grid Background="{Binding Text, ElementName=TB}">
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100" Name="TB"/>
</Grid>
```

Результат:

[image: а чё, прикольно]

---

Если вам в реальности нужно *два* окна, свяжите их через общий `DataContext`:

```
// https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/632894/10105
class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string colorName;
    public string ColorName
    {
        get => colorName;
        set => Set(ref colorName, value);
    }

    protected bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
            return false;

        field = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Теперь в первом окне

```
<Grid Background="{Binding ColorName}">
</Grid>
```

и во втором

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ColorName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но я имела в виду из другой формы. Есть две формы: в одной пишешь цвет, а в другой меняет , посредством обычного кода, а не путем разметки

Comment: @Veronika формы? не окна?

Comment: @Veronika: Ну так протяните значение через VM, например, делов-то. А почему вам обязательно через код?

Comment: Ну задание у меня такое по C#, по этому и обязательно

Comment: @Veronika: Задание состоит в том, чтобы не использовать VM? o_O

Comment: ну нет такого в задании

Answer (score 0):

Подписываетесь на событие `TextChanged` и в нём пишете следующий код:

```
private void RichTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Color color = Color.FromName(richTextBox.Text);

    if (color.IsKnownColor)
        form2.BackColor = color;
}
```

`form2` - это ссылка на другую форму.

Comment: как подписаться на событие TextChanged?
Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства "Form.BackColor" требуется ссылка на объект. и еще одна ошибка 'Form2" не содержит определения для "richTextBox2_TextChanged" и не удалось найти метод расширения "richTextBox2_TextChanged", принимающий тип "Form2" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку).

Answer (score 0):

Странная архитектура требует странных решений. Попробуйте во второй форме объявить статическое свойство Queue. В первой форме класть туда, во-второй выбирать. 
Т.е. пример выше будет:

```
private void RichTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Color color = Color.FromName(richTextBox.Text);

    if (color.IsKnownColor)
        Form2.QueueBackColor.Enqueue(color);
}
```

Comment: Объявить свойство Queue через  { get; set; }?

Comment: public static Queue<Color> QueueBackColor { get; set; }

Comment: Знаете, а лучше всего объявите как public переменную:
public static Queue<Color> QueueBackColor = new Queue<Color>();