# Как обновить интерфейс при изменении элемента ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, uwp

Есть класс Client:

```
public class Client : INotifyPropertyChanged // Клиент
{
    public int Code { get; set; }           // Код клиента в базе данных
    public string Name { get; set; }        // Имя клиента
    public string Patronymic { get; set; }  // Отчество клиента
    public string Surname { get; set; }     // Фамилия клиента
    public string MobilePhone { get; set; } // Номер мобильного телефона
    public string Email { get; set; }       // Адрес электронной почты
    public string Skype { get; set; }       // Учетная запись Skype
    public string WhatsApp { get; set; }    // Учетная запись WhatsApp
    public string Telegram { get; set; }    // Учетная запись Telegram
    public string Comments { get; set; }    // Комментарии

    public string FullName                  // ФИО клиента
    {
        get
        {
            return Name + " " + Patronymic + " " + Surname;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Создана коллекция элементов этого класса:

```
private ObservableCollection<Client> Clients; // Список всех клиентов
```

Данные из этой коллекции отображаются в интерфейсе:

```
<GridView x:Name="gvClients" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="gvClients_ItemClick">
    <GridView.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Width="50" Text="Код"/>
                <TextBlock Width="130" Text="Имя"/>
                <TextBlock Width="130" Text="Отчество"/>
                <TextBlock Width="130" Text="Фамилия"/>
                <TextBlock Width="130" Text="Мобильный тел."/>
                <TextBlock Width="130" Text="Email"/>
                <TextBlock Width="130" Text="Skype"/>
                <TextBlock Width="130" Text="WhatsApp"/>
                <TextBlock Width="130" Text="Telegram"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.HeaderTemplate>
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Client">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Width="50" Text="{x:Bind Code}"/>
                <TextBlock Width="130" Text="{x:Bind Name}"/>
                <TextBlock Width="130" Text="{x:Bind Patronymic}"/>
                <TextBlock Width="130" Text="{x:Bind Surname}"/>
                <TextBlock Width="130" Text="{x:Bind MobilePhone}"/>
                <TextBlock Width="130" Text="{x:Bind Email}"/>
                <TextBlock Width="130" Text="{x:Bind Skype}"/>
                <TextBlock Width="130" Text="{x:Bind WhatsApp}"/>
                <TextBlock Width="130" Text="{x:Bind Telegram}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

Источник данных для GridView:

```
gvClients.ItemsSource = Clients;
```

При добавлении или удалении элемента в коллекцию GridView обновляется. Проблема возникает при изменении элемента коллекции, GridView такие изменения не отображает.
Подскажите, как изменить код, чтобы при изменении элемента коллекции эти изменения отображались в GridView

Добавил вызов метода NotifyPropertyChanged в свойство MobilePhone:

```
private int mobilePhone;
public int MobilePhone    
{
    get
    {
        return mobilePhone;
    }
    set
    {
        mobilePhone = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("MobilePhone");
    }
}
```

Все равно UI не обновляется при изменении свойства MobilePhone. Что ещё не так?

Comment: Реализуйте `INotifyPropertyChanged`...

Comment: Так вроде бы уже реализовал, но не работает

Comment: Нет, не реализовали. У вас пустые свойства, без какой либо логики, а должны вызывать метод оповещения от INPC.

Comment: А вы не могли пример дать как это сделать?

Comment: [к примеру тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/197067/Для-чего-нужны-свойства/197075#197075) или [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/632517/Гексагональная-сетка/632894#632894). Видов реализации этого много, но основная  суть в том, что вы в set нужного свойства вызываете INPC метод и он уже обновляет интерфейс. А в вашем случае вы реализовали методы, но не как их не вызываете!

Comment: Я прописал вызов INPC метода в свойстве MobilePhone (см. исходный вопрос). Все равно при изменении значения этого свойства UI не обновляется.

Comment: А как и где свойство меняете?

Comment: Свойство меняю в программе по нажатию кнопки. Как-то примерно вот так: Clients.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Code == SelectedClient.Code).MobilePhone = newMobilePhone; Оно меняется, проверял, выводил в Debug его значение после изменения. Но изменение не отображается в UI.

Comment: См. ответ, надеюсь понятно :)

Comment: Вот теперь заработало. Спасибо. Mode=OneWay я раньше пробовал устанавливать, но без вызова в сеттере свойства INPC метода. Все вместе работает

Comment: Можно еще попробовать указать для всего `GridView` `x:DefaultBindMode="OneWay"`, чтобы не указывать явно в каждой привязке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

См.: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension

> `{x:Bind}` имеет режим по умолчанию `OneTime`, в отличие от `{Binding}` с режимом по умолчанию `OneWay`. Он был выбран в целях повышения производительности, поскольку при использовании `OneWay` создается больший объем кода для подключения и обнаружения изменений. Можно явно задать режим, чтобы использовать привязку `OneWay` или `TwoWay`. ...